# How I solve this error with the split function?

Tags: list, split

I have written the following code and seem to be getting an error, can anyone help? I am using python 3.

Input code:

```
def fruits(h):
  ingredients = fruits.split()
  print(ingredients)

print(fruits("apples berries honey"])
```

Output:

```
    ingredients = fruits.split()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Did you mean `ingredients = h.split()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method called `split()` with a function name.
`split()` function only exists as a method of String type. Thus, you must call and invoke `split()` with a String type variable not a function.

Maybe, the argument `h` is a String. So you might want to do `h.split()`

And you also have the closing bracket, when you call

```py
print(fruits("apples berries honey"])
```

please modify this code to down below:

```py
print(fruits("apples berries honey"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've understood where I went wrong.